# Traduction courante/pseudo-savante du « XY problem » ?

Tags: sens, traduction, anglais, usage

Le « [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) » est un type de problème où on nous dit qu'on « asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem » ([Community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)) ; on demande de l'aide au sujet de sa tentative Y plutôt que de son problème X, pour ainsi dire...

---

Quel est le sens du *XY problem* en français ; comment le décrit-on, comment l'explique-t-on , comment le nomme/traduit-on : est-ce le *problème XY* ? Comment exprime-t-on ça couramment, précisément, et dans ce dernier cas est-ce à l'aide de locutions latines courantes en français, et si oui lesquelles ? Est-ce d'usage général tel quel, est-ce du vocabulaire technique ?

Comment: Un [programmeur francophone](https://www.matthecat.com/probleme-xy/). Sur [Github](https://gist.github.com/nicolasblanco/5933692) en français.

Comment: That second link in particular does a great job of explaining the criteria for an XY problem in French!

Comment: You might want to read this explanation of where this originated: https://daniel-lange.com/archives/69-The-XY-problem-in-IT-management.html

Comment: Did you read the second link Laure shared? It's certainly an approach to an expression of the concept in French, if in bullet points rather than technically...

"Généralement le schéma est le suivant :

- L'utilisateur veut faire X.
- L'utilisateur ne sait pas comment faire X mais pense qu'il pourra obtenir une solution s'il commence par faire Y.
- L'utilisateur ne sait aussi pas faire Y.
- L'utilisateur demande de l'aide pour faire Y.
- Les autres personnes essayent d'aider l'utilisateur à faire Y mais ces derniers ont des doutes sur la résolution de Y."

Comment: It differs from a "confusion" in that it's a subtype of confusion. It differs from a "pointless question" in that the point is disguised. If there's a *non sequitur* aspect to it it's the asker's thinking that their solution is necessitated by the problem when it is not. The concept rests on a coherent "taxonomy of problems" rather than on a cost analysis (I think; though Lambie's link shows that it certainly could factor into an analysis of lost time and effort). It's not merely a means of softening the blow or pulling a punch. It's a useful way to roll back progress down the wrong path...

Comment: ...which solutions that follow the asker's assumptions would otherwise do. Correctly identifying an XY problem allows you to avoid misdirecting energy at a doomed solution; in that sense it provides a fail-fast if you take the problem in puzzle-solving terms. It's not a refusal of an "intuitive approach" because it's often a lack of the intuition gained by experience that leads a beginner down the wrong path in the first place, and its presence that allows an expert to walk back down said wrong path to the origin...

Comment: I'm not sure what else you're looking for (as with many of your questions — not that they aren't useful, just very multifaceted). I'm sure the above can be expressed in French and I think the resources linked show that the genus would be recognized by the name "problème XY".

Comment: Ah, I see re: Wooledge. I'm not sure of the connection to French if the taxonomy of the XY problem is the question, but I'd say it's not a logical error... it's a methodology error: one should always show the starting point and not only where one has gotten, in case one took the wrong path. More than that I can't say...

Comment: Moi, je dirais en français, résoudre un problème x avec une solution y. Si vous cherchez à maintenir l'aspect mateux/informatique de la chose et ne pas s'aventurer sur d'autres terrains. Je ne vois pas le problème. C'est assez évident comme expression.

Comment: @Volée de chênes et rosiers Avant de se tremper dans l'obscurantisme, il vaut mieux faire clair, comme disait Lacan( qu'il fasse clair quand il fait jour). Il faut savoir ce que l'on veut dans la vie. Je vois mal comment on peut remplacer une expression pseudo-mathématique par des métaphores agricoles ou fruitières. Et pour le **coiné**, je passe. Je ne connais que le koinè, désolée !

Comment: "Le XY problem c'est utilisé couramment sur SE pour décrire certaines questions, pas des équations." Un problème x avec une solution x. Très simple. Pas d'équation du tout. I don't think you're really interested in anything except in criticizing the phrase. I ain't no big deal this phrase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pour autant que je puisse en juger, l'expression a très clairement sa source dans la culture *hacker* (dans son sens original de "bidouillage informatique plus ou moins amateur"). En tout cas, je n'avais jamais rencontré même le *concept* de la chose avant de voir cette question.

De ce point de vue, je doute fortement que le terme ait une forme admise, même chez les informaticiens francophones (autre qu'une traduction directe, s'entend). Il y a peut-être des expressions qui s'en approchent en psychologie ou en management (voire chez Scott Adams), remarque.

Comment: En près de 40 ans mon nez plongé dans les ordinateurs et les revues et autres publications informatiques, je n'ai jamais vu de référence non plus à cette expression en français. *The XY Problem* est effectivement courant en anglais (et peut-être est-ce du à une certaine mentalité, différente de l'approche des Français, chez nos amis anglo-saxons).

Comment: L'origine n'est pas chez les hackers. C'est faux.

Comment: Peut-être n'avons-nous pas d'équivalent, car c'est simplement le quotidien de l'informaticien. Pas besoin d'un terms spécial. Etre informaticien, c'est dealer avec le "XY problem" tous les jours, en quelque sorte.